# React-bootstrap-table2 doesn't show data from Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-bootstrap-table

I've been trying to retrieve data from Firebase Realtime Database and display it in a react-bootstrap-table2, but I've run into some issues when it comes to actually displaying the data. When I run the code no value is printed into the table, however, there is no error in console. If I set the number of displayed values in the table to 25, an error occurs: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timestamp' of undefined. However, if I console.log timestamp I first get an empty array and then an array with the timestamped values (see the screenshot below).

Here is my code:

```
const App = () => {
  const timestamp = [];
  const getTimestamp = () => {
    const database = db.ref().child("timestamped_measures");
    database.on("value", (ts_measures) => {
      ts_measures.forEach((ts_measure) => {
        const array = {
          time: ts_measure.val().timestamp,
        };
        timestamp.push(array);
      });
    });
  };

  const columns = [{ dataField: "time", text: "Timestamp" }];
  useEffect(() => {
    getTimestamp();
  }, []);
  console.log(timestamp);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BootstrapTable
        keyField="timestamp"
        data={timestamp}
        columns={columns}
        pagination={paginationFactory()}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[This is what my Firebase database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejNUC.png)

[This is what my page and console look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQbMx.png)

[When the pagination is set from 10 to 25, this is what the error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKRbx.png)

Does anyone know why my version doesn't work? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using functional component so make use of hooks for setting state, this will re-render your component after setting your state:

```
const App = () => {
  // Make timestamp state
  const {timestampList, setTimestampList} = React.useState([]);      

  const timestamp = [];
  const getTimestamp = () => {
    const database = db.ref().child("timestamped_measures");
    database.on("value", (ts_measures) => {
      ts_measures.forEach((ts_measure) => {
        const array = {
          time: ts_measure.val().timestamp,
        };
        timestamp.push(array);
      });
        
        // Set array to timestamp state array
        setTimestampList(timestamp);

    });
  };

  const columns = [{ dataField: "time", text: "Timestamp" }];
  useEffect(() => {
    getTimestamp();
  }, []);
  console.log(timestamp);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BootstrapTable
        keyField="timestamp"
        data={timestampList} // Pass timestamp state to data prop
        columns={columns}
        pagination={paginationFactory()}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After trying the suggestion I got this error: _Failed prop type: The prop `data` is marked as required in `DataProvider`, but its value is `undefined`_.I tried to console.log timestamp and the array was empty. I also tried to console.log timestampList and got undefined.

Comment: @Nina make sure its React.useState([]) . If you still get undefined then it means there is something wrong in your loop, try debugging it and make sure it has array before         setTimestampList(timestamp);

Comment: I copied the code you posted above, so I did use the React.useState([]). I don't think there is a problem with my loop, since it works fine with the code I first posted.

Comment: Then its probably timestamp is undefined, check by console.log(timestamp) before         setTimestampList(timestamp);

Comment: When I console.log(timestamp) before setTimestampList(timestamp) it doesn't write anything to the console. So does that mean that it's undefined?

Comment: @Nina Yes you dont have data in your timestamp which leads to undefined, make sure you are querying correctly from database

Comment: I don't think there should be a problem with querying, because it works with the initial code. Do you think that the modified code could affect the querying?

Comment: @Nina No modified does not effect querying